# Ruby Gems on Windows

Tags: windows, ruby, rubygems

I have removed and reinstalled ruby on my machine (windows 7, ruby 1.9.1). When I go to get rails again I get: While executing gem... File Exists C:

Yet when I list my gems is says none are installed.

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

This is a permissions issue. On Windows, you need to run as admin when you're installing gems.